# How to record a stream

Tags: java

I need to record a stream of data as it passes from my application to another application (both under my control).

I want to do this to record the bytes sent and received for integration testing.

I can do something like this:

```
void inputStreamToOutputStream(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream out) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                int d;
                while ((d = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(d);
                    savedFile.write(d);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

But it feels like there should already be a library to do this. I can see that Apache IOUtils has a `copy` method to tie two streams together:

```
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

But this doesn't let me 'record' the bytes sent. Before I go rolling my own, can anyone suggest a decent library that already does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html)/[TeeInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) from Apache Commons IO, you could write to your output as well as to your `savedInFile` and `savedOutFile`:

```
OutputStream teeOutput = new TeeOutputStream(out, savedOutFile);
InputStream teeInput = new TeeInputStream(input, savedInFile)
```

and then you can send the tees to your application that does the reading/writing.

Comment: Just to minimize confusion, I suggest "tee" above to use "savedOutFile" and "teeInput" above to use "savedInFile". The API does not specify what happens when more than one stream use the same file.

Comment: @A.J. Good suggestion, I'll fix my post

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer mentioned, you can use [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from CommonsIO, but you will still need to buffer your input stream properly. The code you included was close, but you were merely writing the number of bytes read out to the two streams, *not* the bytes themselves.

Try something like this instead:

```
void inputStreamToOutputStream(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream out) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                TeeOutputStream tos = new TeeOutputStream (out,savedFile);
                byte [] buf = byte[1024];
                int d;
                while ((d = inputStream.read(buf,0,buf.length)) != -1) {
                    tos.write(buf,0,d);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```